# Elasticsearch - Retrieve index status with query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like to attach the index status to my Elasticsearch query to fetch not only the data but also how reliable that data is. Is it possible?

Slightly related, is it possible to know the index lag as part of its status?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "index status" and "how reliable the data is"? Can you explain your use case and/or worries?

Comment: @Val I take a lag threshold that determines when some data in ES may be too old/stale to be considered as trustworthy, following business logic variants. So I'd like to query that data and immediately know if it is acceptably in sync with the source or it's too old and I should fallback to MYSQL.

Comment: You mean you have a date field in your documents that conveys some kind of "freshness" status of the data present in the document?

Comment: @Val No, I can give an example: I search by location depending on stock availability. I can tolerate some lag in that data because stock doesn't decrease each second, but if it is too out of sync then I need to discard it because I'd direct other physical resources to the wrong location.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't quite get your definition of "lag" and "out of sync"... How do you expect to detect that lag what concrete and actionable data can you use?

Comment: @Val That's the root question for the post. 
"if (index_lag > 60 seconds) fetch_from_mysql();"

Is anything like index_lag to be fetched together with the query for data? Or at least attach the existing GET _cat/indices/my_index?h=index,health&v

Comment: Well, I got that, but it heavily depends on your input pipeline and what all your components do between the time the data is fetched from your DB until it is indexed into ES and refreshed (i.e. ready for search)... In order to define a lag, you need to points of reference, the end time (i.e. refresh time is known = 1s after indexing time by default), and the start time (i.e. when the data is fetched) which in your case is kind of blurry.